# Issue with bootstrap.ini on MDT

Tags: hp, mdt, windows-pe

I have an odd problem with my MDT Deployment.

If I use the following bootstrap.ini, when MDT starts it goes straight to a screen saying "Specify which deployment share to use"

```
[Settings]
Priority=DefaultGateway, Default

[DefaultGateway]
192.168.10.1=Test

[Test]
DeployRoot=\\xxxxMDT01\MDTProduction$
UserDomain=TEST
UserID=MDT_BA
UserPassword=xxxxxxx

[Default]
SkipBDDWelcome=YES
```

[image: Specify which deployment share]

However when I use the following boostrap.ini without the DefaultGateway specification, the deployment works.

```
[Settings]
Priority=Default

[Default]
DeployRoot=\\xxxxMDT01\MDTProduction$
UserDomain=TEST
UserID=MDT_BA
UserPassword=xxxxxxx
SkipBDDWelcome=YES
```

I have tested on two different HP models.

I have included the HP Win 10 PE drivers that can be found here:
https://ftp.hp.com/pub/caps-softpaq/cmit/HP_WinPE_DriverPack.html

I have also tried changing my DHCP source from my router to my domain controller.

If anyone can shed any light on this issue I's be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the issue was related to the network connectivity.

This fixed my issue.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/deploymentguys/making-winpe-wait-for-network-in-lti-deployments